# How to enable EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation via code?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query) you need to add the following to your `applicationInsights.config` file to enable full SQL logging:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
    <EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>true</EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>
</Add>
```

But in my ASP.NET app running on .NET Framework 4.7.2 hosted in an Azure App Service I'm enabling/configuring Application Insights via code:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = false;
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = setting.ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey;
```

How can I enable this setting via code?

P.S.: The settings in the Web App are correctly enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It seems even if AI is enabled via code it picks up the settings from the config file.
I added it to my `applicationInsights.config` and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

In `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(o => { ... });

    services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>(
        (module, o) => { module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; }
    );
}
```

I looks like Microsoft has added the code configuration to their documentation now:

- [Advanced SQL tracking to get full SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but thats for ASP.NET Core, my app is still on the old ASP.NET 4.x